# while sending android push notification to thousand of user getting 405 error

Tags: php, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Please help me with this issue while sending push notification to more than thousands of user i stuck with 405 error.Below is code for push notification

```
function androidPush($regid,$message,$title,$imageUrl='',$url)
{

        if (!defined('API_ACCESS_KEY')) define('API_ACCESS_KEY', 'mykey');
            $registrationIds = array_filter($regid);
            $Regid = array();
            foreach($registrationIds as $rid){
            $Regid[] = $rid;
            }

            if(empty($registrationIds) || $title==""){
                return false;
            }else{

            $msg = array
            (
            'message' => html_entity_decode(trim($message)),
            'title' => $title,
            'image' => $imageUrl, 
             'url' =>html_entity_decode(trim($url)),
            'vibrate' => 1,
            'sound' => 1
             );
            $fields = array();
            $fields['data'] = $msg;
            $Idcount =  count($Regid);
            if($Idcount > 1000)
            {   

             $newId =    array_chunk($Regid, 1000);
             for($i = 0;$i < count($newId);$i++){
                $fields['registration_ids'] = $newId[$i];
                $headers = array
                (
                'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
                'Content-Type: application/json'
                );
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
                curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
                curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
                curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
                curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
                curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
                $result = curl_exec($ch );
                curl_close( $ch );
             }
               return $result;
             }  else{
                 $fields['registration_ids'] = $Regid;

                    $headers = array
                    (
                    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
                    'Content-Type: application/json'
                    );
                    $ch = curl_init();
                    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
                    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
                    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
                    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
                    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
                    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
                    $result = curl_exec($ch);
                    curl_close( $ch );
                    return $result;
                         }

                }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think maybe you're using an old endpoint? `https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send`. I think the current GCM endpoint is `https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send`.

Answer (score 0):

405 error states that Method Not Allowed [more](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E405.html)

try adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, POST);`

because i think gcm code expects post request..

Comment: my concern is  that when i am using this function user get notification but response goes 405 error.